# Using external libraries in phoenix LiveView

Tags: elixir, tinymce, phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

I am trying to integrate the WYSIWYG-Editor tinymce with a phoenix LiveView that contains textarea fields. Before using LiveView, I imported it as a node_module library into the app.js file

```
import tinymce from '../node_modules/tinymce/tinymce'
```

and then initialized it through

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  plugins: ...
})
```

In order to be able to validate the form inputs in a template, I transformed it into a LiveView which I serve through

```
let csrfToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
let liveSocket = new LiveSocket("/live", Socket, {params: {_csrf_token: csrfToken}, hooks: Hooks});

//// Connect if there are any LiveViews on the page
liveSocket.connect();
```

as is customary. However, as soon as the LiveSocket is mounted, the tinymce-plugin does not work anymore and there remains only a basic textarea field on which the intended validation is carried out, nonetheless.

Is there a way to load this external library into the LiveView? I tried to call a function containing the tinymce.init step through a hook

```
let Hooks = {}
Hooks.LoadIt = {
  mounted() {
    tinyinit(tinymce)
  }
}
```

but this does not work. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could attach your hook to the element. Something like this:

```
<textarea ... phx-hook="LoadIt" id="your-unique-id"></textarea>
```

And initialize it in mounted:

```
Hooks.LoadIt = {
 mounted() {
    tinymce.init({
     selector: this.el, # <- attribute referencing the bound DOM node.
     plugins: ...
    })
  }
}
```

Learn more about client hooks: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_live_view/js-interop.html#client-hooks

Comment: I had it right, actually, but made a minor mistake elsewhere...